# Change default locaton that tfs reporting datasources are created

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

The Reporting Taxonomy guru in my office has requested that during our next TFS upgrade, that the datasources Tfs2010ReportDS and Tfs2010OlapReportDS not be placed right in the root/home folder of the reporting server.  He would like all tfs datasources and tfs reports tucked away in their own tfsreports folder.  While the reports install nicely in a folder, the datasources appear to have no way to control where they are created. Specifying a folder within the TFS administration console while configuring report appears to affect only reports, not datasources.  While I could move the datasources after they are created, I fear that I would break all the reports that depend on the datasource and force me to manually update each one.  Because we didn't follow best practices of keeping everything in one team project, this would require that I visit 50+ reports.  Am I missing a some setting somewhere that controls where the datasources are created?

P.S. we are recreating all reports as a part of the upgrade using this MSDN article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn148128.aspx) and powertools, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by TFS and as per the documentation it owns both the instance of RS and SQL and any change to the documented installation and permissions will negate your support agreement with MS (invalidate the warranty).

However you can achieve it if those pushing for this change are willing to take on that support from MS. They will need to manually configure all reports up from, and then continue to manually update the reports when a new team project is created. This procedure may need to be reverted and redone every time you upgrade TFS so they are taking on this task on a quarterly basis.

I would recommend that you NOT do this and explain to them that the instances of RS, AS, and SQL used by TFS are owned and managed by the application itself and that they should keep their grubby paws off of it. 90% of all issues I see in the field (I have been a TFS consultant since 2010) in TFS configuration and upgrade are due to DBA's believing that they know better than the product team.

TFS and all its systems should be a black box managed by your TFS Support team.

Comment: Better yet, move to VSO and negate their power entirely.